# PHP OCI8 installation on mac sierra

Tags: php, macos-sierra, oci8

Is anyone know how to install PHP OCI8 extension on macOS Sierra (10.12.6)? I tried to follow the steps given here http://www.enavigo.com/2012/01/04/enabling-oracle-oci8-php-extension-on-os-x-snow-leopard/ but stuck on the step where it says copy files under /usr/include folder. Looks like copying to that folder is not allowed in new OS version? I tried googling but didn't find any good answer. All answers are related to old OS versions. Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The [Instant Client installation instructions for macOS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html#ic_osx_inst) say you can link from `~/lib` (as an alternative to `/usr/local/lib`).

Unzip the Instant Client Basic & SDK packages to `~/instantclient_12_1` and then run:

```
mkdir ~/lib
ln -s ~/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.dylib ~/lib/
```

This is what I do: just one symbolic link to my local Instant Client directory.

Now you can build PHP and/or OCI8.  If you are using PECL and PHP 7 you could run

```
pecl install oci8
```

and answer the prompt with:

```
instantclient,/Users/yourname/instantclient_12_1
```

Don't use something like `$HOME`, since `pecl` won't expand variables.

If you are building PHP yourself, your `configure` option could be something like:

```
configure --with-oci8=instantclient,$HOME/instantclient_12_1 . . .
```